# How should an apache module communicate with a separate running process mid-request?

Tags: c, apache

I am looking to design a system system as follows:

- Apache module to allow/deny requests
- Standalone program containing logic to allow/deny requests

How precisely could the Apache module be made to communicate with a standalone program without introducing a huge performance hit (without reading/writing files)?

For example `apr_file_open` can be used to write files from an Apache module but that would be very slow.

Comment: Kind of impossible to say without more details, but this is just inter-process communication. So sockets, pipes, files would all work, or layered on top of that, http, websockets etc.

Comment: @Paul You may be right but there's usually a right way to do things in Apache as someone's done it before or Apache may have something useful built in I don't know about - that's why I kept it as general as I could.